# How can I show the name of a belongs_to model on my Index page in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, indexing

I have two models in Rails. A task and a status. I have put the relationships in the models correctly. A task belongs to a status and a status has_many tasks. So far so good.

However when showing all my tasks on the index page (see my `index.html.erb` below) I cannot show the status field correctly.

What should I put in my tasks controller and what code should I put in my `index.html.erb` file below?

The status model only has a name in it and each task has a foreign key status_id in the database. The statusses are for instance "Open" and "Closed". I cannot get these statusses shown on my index page of all the tasks.

Thanks.

```
<h1>Listing tasks</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Activity</th>
    <th>List</th>
    <th>Context</th>
    <th>Descripton</th>
    <th>Project</th>
    <th>Deadline</th>
    <th>Owner</th>
    <th>Delegated to</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Estimated hours</th>
    <th>Remaining hours</th>
    <th>Closed on</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @tasks.each do |task| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= task.activity %></td>
    <td><%= task.list%></td>
    <td><%= task.descripton %></td>
    <td><%= task.project %></td>
    <td><%= task.deadline %></td>
    <td><%= task.owner %></td>
    <td><%= task.delegated_to %></td>
    <td><%= @status.name %></td> ?????????? Here I want to put my status name f.i. "Open" of that task.
    <td><%= task.estimated_hours %></td>
    <td><%= task.remaining_hours %></td>
    <td><%= task.closed_on %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', task %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_task_path(task) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', task, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br />

<%= link_to 'New Task', new_task_path %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to take a guess, because like the first commenter I found the post extremely difficult to read.

So if you have a Task and Status and they are setup correctly then you can access the status by simply using:

```
task.status.name
```

Now in your controller you will want to include the Status. This can be done very easily.

```
Task.find(:all, :include => :status)
```

You will want to make sure to add an index to your database on tasks.status_id.

Hope this helps =)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should be able to get at it as simply as:

```
<%= task.status.name %>
```